# Unable to connect to broker using TLS librdkafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python, librdkafka

I'm quite new at using this library in conjunction with confluent kafka python. I have an envrioment in JAVA KAFKA - in which i'm able to successfuly connect to the broker and I want to do the same thing on the python client. For JAVA KAFKA i created a .csr and have a .key too. The CSR was signed and i received back the ca.pem and another .pem file. I then used these files to create a .p12 file and from that the keystore file and the truststore file. In Java client I'm running the following command:

```bash
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server xxxx:9193 --topic gtest --group testgroup--consumer-property 'security.protocol=SSL' --consumer-property 'sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512' --consumer-property 'ssl.truststore.location=x_trust.jks' --consumer-property 'ssl.keystore.location=x_key.jks' --consumer-property 'ssl.keystore.password=*****' --consumer-property 'ssl.truststore.type=JKS' --consumer-property 'ssl.truststore.password=****' --from-beginning
```

And it works fine. As far as I know, librdkafka client I can't use these .jks files, so how to i get on to connect using python? I've tried using the .p12 in librdkafka as keystore + password but doesn't work :(

Any help is appreaciated!

To connect to broker. Currently i'm seeing following error:

```
%3|1710150782.663|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator: x:9194 SSL handshake failed: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed: broker certificate could not be verified, verify that ssl.ca.location is correctly configured or root CA certificates are installed (install ca-certificates package) (after 73ms in state SSL_HANDSHAKE)
```

I also don't understand, I'm trying to connect to port 9193, and error is on port 9194?